# Need to add custom file extension to registry from Visual Studio InstallShield LE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, file-extension, installshield-le

I've been able to add custom file extensions by using: Project >> Properties >> Publish >> Options >> File Associations in the past. However I much prefer to use InstallShield as my installer as opposed to Click Once applications (my users find this more native, and freak out less at updates).

I'm much less experienced with InstallShield and only know the basics, how can I add a custom file extension along with my install?

A quick back story on why I want to do this is that we're going to be moving this entire system over to an ERP system (Navision) in the next year or so. In the mean time I'm attempting to add a layer of security to the files currently created along with each customer order, by forcing the user to open these files in this application. This way, we ensure any updates in these files are replicated on our SQL servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an InstallShield project to your VS solution.
Use the projectassistent if you don't have to much experience with it.

You can find a basic tutorial here: http://www.flexerasoftware.com/webdocuments/productdemos/IS2010_VSLE_Demo/IS2010_VSLE_Demo-lite.html